# How does chromosome cross-over occur?

Tags: genetics

I have heard that during meiosis, homologous chromosomes from each parent "cross-over", which enables the off-spring to inherit some alleles from the mother and some alleles from the father.  The picture below illustrates this "cross-over", but of course this must occur at multiple sites, rather than just the one shown in the picture.

[image]

Now my question is what causes the chromosomes to align perfectly during cross-over so that the loci of a particular gene will substitute for the corresponding loci on the homologous chromosome, as opposed to being substituted with a completely random locus?  Does each gene have a unique non coding sequence before it specifying what gene it is to enable this process to occur?

Comment: You might enjoy reading  the section on crossing over from Bruce Alberts' The Cell. I love that book as it has answers to many beautiful questions that may arise regarding cell biology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply, because chromosome pairing is sequence specific. Holliday Junctions, which are the functional structures of a cross-over, occur through a process called "strand invasion," during which a region of one chromosome physically base-pairs with that of another.  Thus one locus cannot pair with a random locus, as there is generally insufficient sequence complimentarity between two random regions to form a functional Holliday Junction.  One interesting consequence of this mechanism is gene duplication and deletion in repetitious regions of the chromosome.  For example, genes with large repeated regions, such as the [gene responsible for Huntington's disease](http://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/condition/huntington-disease), can expand and contract during homologous recombination due to strand invasion occurring at non-equivalent, but still homologous, sites.  Wikipedia does a nice job going over homologous recombination.  I also recommend looking over the relevant sections in Molecular Biology of the Cell, [available](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26840/) on the PubMed Bookshelf.

Comment: Most of the time sequence differences between alleles are quite small.  Two genes with large changes between them are not alleles, they're homologs.  Alleles tend to have one or a few Single Nucleotide Polymorphisms (SNPs) that distinguish them.  For example, the gene that causes sickle cell anemia, differs from the wild type allele by only a single base change. http://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/genetic-mutation-441.  These very small changes are irrelevant in the context of a 10 Kb cross over.